# get session in php page

Tags: php

how can i get all the SESSION variables in a particular php page?

Comment: What do you mean by all the SESSION?  Do you mean all of the session variables?

Comment: All the session OR all the session variable? Both are different thing

Comment: Yes i update my question. i am sorry i mean session variables and already get the answer.Will accept the anwser. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get it by

```
foreach($_SESSION as $k=>$v)
    echo "$k=>$v";
```

OR

```
print_r($_SESSION)
```

OR

```
var_dump($_SESSION)
```

It is to be remember that php $_SESSION is a global array.

Answer (score 4):

`var_dump($_SESSION);` would give you all the session stuff associated with the server it is requested from.

But because your question is unclear, I have no idea if this is what you're looking for.